# Put logo and custom graphic in top header on Divi Wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is it possible to put logo and a custom graphic in the "top-header" (ie. To the left of the phone number) in the popular ElegentThemes Divi template.

http://www.elegantthemes.com/demo/?theme=Divi

I have tried using absolute positioning and setting the container/body to relative. The code can be accessed by inpect-element.

Comment: This question is better suited for Elegant Themes support: http://www.elegantthemes.com/contact.html

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: yes, it is possible. Changing the structure (i.e. the HTML) of a theme, however, is not recommended for many reasons: you may break other parts of the site and/or when you update the theme, any changes you made will be lost. Furthermore, looking at the theme with the link you provided, there is already a place for the logo.